# bullet not appearing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i have tried making bullet in pygame  using this tutorial https://youtu.be/8wEYDLVrAB8 but i have failed to do so here is commented  code ,
. if problem arise please leave a comment on it . thank you for helping .i have already asked it once in this website but it didnt work [![  this is current state when firing bullet][1]][1] . i am running it in pycharm

```
import pygame
import random
#module importing
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
#screen creation
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
bacground = pygame.image.load("background.png")


#player information
playerimg = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
playerX_change = 0
playerX = 360
playerY = 480

#enemy information
enemyimg = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
enemyX = random.randint(0,736)
enemyY = random.randint(50,150)
enemyX_change = 4
enemyY_change = 40
#bullet information
bulletimg = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 40
bullet_state = "ready"
#all three functions
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))
#enemy draw function
def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyimg, (x, y))


#bullet fire function

def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 16, y+10))


# drawing player on screen



# game loop
running = True

while running == True:
#stuff happening in game loop
    screen.fill((200, 200, 0))
    screen.blit(bacground,(0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change
#detection of the keys pressed and consequences
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            player(playerX, playerY)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0

#player and enemy movement system
    playerX += playerX_change
    enemyX += enemyX_change


#enemy and player collision detection
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX_change = 4
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    if enemyX>= 736:
        enemyX_change = -4
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
#display update

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The bullet image is the same ad the enemy image.

Comment: @Rabbid76 it is a typo i have fixed it

Comment: There many more typos: `if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:` -> `if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:` and `if bullet_state == "fire:":` -> `if bullet_state == "fire":`. Additionally you have som [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) issues.

Comment: is it ok now or any more typos

Comment: i am still stuck

Comment: Fix the indentation

Comment: i dont see any problem in indentation (sorry for  all this trouble)

Comment: Please look at your code. You have to handel the events **in** the event loop instead of **after** the event loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230330/discussion-between-shreejit-mishra-and-rabbid76).

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to handle the events in the event loop instead of the application loop:

```py
while running == True:
    #stuff happening in game loop
    screen.fill((200, 200, 0))
    screen.blit(bacground,(0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)

    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change
    
    #detection of the keys pressed and consequences
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    # INDENTATAION
    #-->|
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
```